# using Aquila in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

First i make Aquila by Cmake
and then open the `Aquila.sln` file that generated by Cmake
and then from build menu and batch build check the

```
Aquila    Debug     Win32   Debug|Win32
Aquila    Release   Win32   Release|Win32
```

and generate `Aquila.lib` 
and added this library and `.h` files in my solution for running the example but I have this error:

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cdft referenced in
>   function "public: virtual class std::vector,class std::allocator >
>    __thiscall Aquila::OouraFft::fft(double const * const)" (?fft@OouraFft@Aquila@@UAE?AV?$vector@V?$complex@N@std@@V?$allocator@V?$complex@N@std@@@2@@std@@QBN@Z)   C:...\aquila\Aquila.lib(OouraFft.obj)

Then i change Runtime Library from `Multi threaded debuge DLL (/MDd)` to 
`Multi threaded debuge (/MTd)`

> but have this error: Error    1   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for
>   'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value
>   'MTd_StaticDebug' in
>   aquila.obj    C:...\aquila\Aquila.lib(SignalSource.obj)

Aquila example

```
#include "aquila/aquila.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

int main()
{
    // input signal parameters
    const std::size_t SIZE = 64;
    const Aquila::FrequencyType sampleFreq = 2000, f1 = 125, f2 = 700;

    Aquila::SineGenerator sine1(sampleFreq);
    sine1.setAmplitude(32).setFrequency(f1).generate(SIZE);
    Aquila::SineGenerator sine2(sampleFreq);
    sine2.setAmplitude(8).setFrequency(f2).setPhase(0.75).generate(SIZE);
    auto sum = sine1 + sine2;

    Aquila::TextPlot plot("Input signal");
    plot.plot(sum);

    // calculate the FFT
    auto fft = Aquila::FftFactory::getFft(SIZE);
    Aquila::SpectrumType spectrum = fft->fft(sum.toArray());

    plot.setTitle("Spectrum");
    plot.plotSpectrum(spectrum);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any one cane help me????

Answer (score 0):

If you use aquila 3.0, after building aquila with cmake, Ooura_fft.lib must be in aquila-build/lib/Debug/Ooura_fft.lib. You have to link it to your project.

Comment: Please explain your answer in more detail.